# Cipher Suite TLS 1.2 - Weak in OHS

Tags: encryption, tls, webserver, ciphers

I am trying to correct weak encryption in TLS, by doing a test in `SSL Labs`, it throws weak encryption in the following chpher suite:

**Current Configuration:**

```
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL:!AES128:!SHA1
```

**Cipher Suite TLS 1.2 - Weak:**

- **TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x3d) WEAK**
- **TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384    (0x9d) WEAK**

> OHS Version: Oracle-HTTP-Server-11g/11.1.1.9.0 (Unix)
>   mod_ssl/11.1.1.9.0

Try to solve with:

```
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL:!AES128:!SHA1:!SHA256:!SHA384

SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXPORT

SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS

SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!RC4:!LOW:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!3DES:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS 

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL:!AES128:!SHA1:!TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256:!TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

None of these settings worked for my SSL configuration in OHS.

Someone has eliminated those two issues in weak encryption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ciphers are considered weak by SSLLabs since they use RSA key exchange which provides no forward secrecy. To disable RSA key exchange in your ciphers add `!kRSA`. In general, just use the [Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) to give you a secure setting.

Comment: To add to this, ciphers that support forward secrecy will contain "DHE" or "ECDHE".

Comment: Try with  :  `SSLCipherSuite HIGH:ECDHE:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL:!AES128:!SHA1:!kRSA`  //not working
and delete remove the last parameter `!kRSA`  and working configuration, now test with ssl Labs

Comment: current configuration: `SSLCipherSuite HIGH:ECDHE:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL:!AES128:!SHA1`
 add `ECDHE` parameter

Comment: @Ventur: what do you exactly mean with *"not working"*? Failure to start, SSLLabs shows only errors, unable to connect with browser, unable to connect with a specific client or what? Also, adding ECDHE (your next try) does not remove the ciphers with RSA key exchange.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich with not working is  unable to conect with browser, not displayed web page if add  `!kRSA`.

Comment: @Ventur: What kind of browser did you try? What does SSLLabs say if you add `!kRSA`?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich try in IE 11 and  google chrome Versión 67.0.3396.87 (Build oficial) (32 bits) and  page can’t be displayed with `!kRSA`. I will just run the test in ssl labs

Answer (score 2):

If those ciphers are not working while RSA is then you may have a wrong certificate. If the *key usage* of the certificate only allows *encryption* (needed for RSA based key establishment in the TLS_RSA_ ciphers) then it won't work for RSA based authentication, which requires the *signature generation* key usage (needed for RSA based authentication in the TLS_DHE_ and TLS_ECDHE ciphers).

You may have to re-apply for a certificate, preferably using a new key pair - you may not want to mix key usages in general, which is why the key usage is in the cert in the first place.